# JSF values not being updated in bean

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

In JSF 1.1, I am having a lot of trouble with passing values. I pass values from bean to a JSF page, but they are not being passed back, causing a NullPointerException. declareFinishList in bean is populated by an initializing method to display on the page, but when I submit I get a nullpointer exception at `for (DeclareFinish df : declareFinishList)` showing that it is not being passed back. The map `declaredFinishMap` also comes out as null. I've done this before so I don't understand why this particular one is having trouble while my other similar tables are working fine.

EDIT: I've managed to pass `declareFinishList` by placing it in session scope, but I still can't seem to pass `declaredFinishMap`.

To note, the bean is defined by rsaleController in faces-config.xml. Entire page is wrapped in h:form that I didn't include.

Bean:

```
public class RetailSaleController extends BaseBean {
    private List<DeclareFinish>     declareFinishList;
    private Map<DeclareFinish, Boolean> declaredFinishMap = new LinkedHashMap<DeclareFinish, Boolean>();

    public void saveDeclareFinishList(ActionEvent event) {
    List<DeclareFinish> list = new ArrayList<DeclareFinish>();
        for (DeclareFinish df : declareFinishList) {
            if(declaredFinishMap.get(df)) {
                list.add(df);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Page:

```or-tag-here
<h:panelGroup id="declareFinishListPanel">
    <rich:dataTable id="declareFinishItemTable" border="1"
        value="#{rsaleController.declareFinishList}" var="item"
        <rich:column width="16">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <rich:spacer height="24px;" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{rowNo+1}" />
        </rich:column>

        <rich:column style="text-align:center;">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Locked" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="reset"
                value="#{rsaleController.declaredFinishMap[item]}" />
        </rich:column>

        <rich:column sortBy="#{item.dealerId}" sortIcon="none;" width="110">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{labels.crmsFldLabDealer}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.dealerId}" />
        </rich:column>

    </rich:dataTable>
</h:panelGroup>

<a4j:commandLink reRender="declareFinishItemTable"
    actionListener="#{rsaleController.saveDeclareFinishList}">
    <h:graphicImage value="/images/save.gif" title="Save changes"
        style="height:16;width:16;border-style:none;vertical-align:middle" />
</a4j:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the code snippit, `declareFinishList` is not getting initialized anywhere, unless that's elsewhere in the code.

Comment: I didn't include the method that initializes it, but it's populated properly when the page loads. Just seems to go blank again on submit so if I change anything, it's not reflected.

Comment: What's the scope of your ManagedBean? Request, View?

Comment: Request. I am actually just reusing the bean; it's already used by other pages, one with a similar function. Don't really know why this new one doesn't work.

Comment: Request scoped beans are created from scratch with each request. I don't know how the list is initialized, but it stands to reason that you lose your previously initialized list and your submit operates on a brand new bean.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines. The map in the page is also returning null even if I check everything, but I have a similar map on the same bean on another page that works just fine in request scope. Honestly I'm just so confused why this one doesn't. If I can get at least the map to be passed properly I can make something of this.

Comment: Are you able to set a breakpoint on the save method and check the values of the actual objects? I wouldn't expect the map to be null, but to see null returned from the EL expression.

Comment: I've used session scope to pass the values properly, only the map is having problems now. It's also now in session scope but is coming out null when I check its values even though it is also initialized.

Comment: Can you add the initialization code to your question? I'm not sure why the map would be null.

Comment: Never mind, I think I solved the problem. Just junked the map and used a boolean value in my `DeclareFinish` object that I set in session scope.